# Cancel RxJava Observable

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, rx-java2

I want upload files with progress bar. I create AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
View dialogView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_upload_view, null);
progress = (NumberProgressBar) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
progress.setProgress(0);
dialog.setView(dialogView);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) -> Log.w("TEST", "Cancel"));
AlertDialog ad = dialog.show();
```

And I upload files next

```
    Disposable disposable = Observable.fromArray(files.toArray())
            .flatMap(photo -> {
                ProgressRequestBody fileBody = new ProgressRequestBody(photo, this);
                MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("userfile", photo.getName(), fileBody);
                return App.getEndpoints().addPhoto(filePart);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnComplete(ad::dismiss)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
```

If I do after

```
dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) -> disposable.dispose());
```

button not show.

How I can set negative button for dialog?

Comment: if the question is how to set a button for dialog, how does it is related to RxJava?

Comment: I want to unsubscribe observable, when click negative button

Comment: Yes, but you wrote that the button does not show, is that problem? Or the observable does not get canceled?

Comment: The Observable will be unsubscribed once the emission finish. Still dont understand the problem